# Jackson POJOPropertyBuilder finds multiple setters in POJO

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, swagger

We're working on a rather large JSON REST API using Spring Web MVC 3.2.2 and Jackson Databind 2.4.4 (among many other libs...).

I'm trying to use [swagger-springmvc](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc), but I'm having troubles with some our DTOs.

No matter if I use a simple `@EnableSwagger` or a more complex swagger config, I always get the following exception when starting Tomcat 7:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "year": javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params) vs javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:303)
at com.mangofactory.swagger.models.Annotations.findPropertyAnnotation(Annotations.java:33)
at com.mangofactory.swagger.models.property.bean.BeanModelProperty.<init>(BeanModelProperty.java:26)
at com.mangofactory.swagger.models.property.bean.BeanModelPropertyProvider.beanModelProperty(BeanModelPropertyProvider.java:166) (...rest of stacktrace )
```

The above mentioned property "year" is just one example, tried the same without the class containing the property year.

The weird thing is that Jackson seams to find the same exact methods / setter twice:
`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params)` vs `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params`

I spent some time with the debugger and noticed that some DTOs seem to pass the check for conflicting setters just fine.

I have now spent many hours on this and couldn't come up with a solution. Most pages for this exception I found with Google talk about overloaded methods / setters, which is not the case with my DTOs - they're simple objects with nothing more than properties, setters and getters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `XMLGregorianCalendar` has two `setYear` methods: `setYear(int year)` and `setYear(BigDecimal year)`. You need to tell swagger to ignore one of them, you can configure a [mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) for the `XMLGregorianCalendar` to only use getters (something like [this](http://stairs-jumper.livejournal.com/33244.html)). This will work if XMLGregorianCalendar is only used in the context of return values.

If that is not the case, you could set up a substitution type, using the `directModelSubstitute` [option](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/blob/master/swagger-springmvc/src/main/java/com/mangofactory/swagger/plugin/SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin.java#L284). When you configure you're `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin` you might try something like one of the options below

```java
@Bean
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin yourPlugin() {
    ...
    plugin.directModelSubstitute(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, String.class)
    //OR this, depending on how you intend to use it and how you want
    // the serialized/deserialized types to appear on the swagger UI
    plugin.directModelSubstitute(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, Date.class)   
    ...
    return plugin
}
```

Or if you dont care about the type being represented in your API documentation, you could [ignore the type as well](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc#excluding-spring-handler-method-arguments-or-custom-types).

Comment: I approved an edit, but it is rather substantial, it would be better as a second answer - if not for the credit .)

Comment: Maybe next time. As you might have guessed by my reputation on SO I'm quite the noob :)

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, would be better if it was a new answer

Comment: Apologies if I overstepped a SO etiquette

Comment: No, I'm glad you improved the quality of my answer, but it is a major edit and you deserve all the credits for any potential upvotes.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the Exception - the problem was my POJO also had the property year, as does the XMLGregorianCalendar Class.
Went with the MixIn, works perfectly.