# Conflict Setter Definition For Property "Year" (Springfox-Swagger2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

My Problem is same as the following question;

[Jackson POJOPropertyBuilder finds multiple setters in POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093270/jackson-pojopropertybuilder-finds-multiple-setters-in-pojo)

But, as i use "springfox-swagger2", i don't use `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin`.

Is there a way i can fix this?

**Application.java**

```
/* Makes this Application Run as Spring Boot Application */
@SpringBootApplication
/* Enables Swagger2API for documentation */
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    LogService.info(Application.class.getName(), "CustomerAPI Service Started");
}

@Bean
public Docket customerApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("Customer Application")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .paths(myAppPaths())
            .build();
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Customer API")
            .description("Some Description to Show")
            .termsOfServiceUrl(null)
            .contact("Test Test")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl(
                    "https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/LICENSE")
            .version("2.0")
            .build();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Predicate<String> myAppPaths() {
    return or(regex("/.*"));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. As Springfox documentation says, `Docket` is very similar to `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin`. So we can do like below, which solves this issue.

```
@Bean
public Docket customerApi() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .directModelSubstitute(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, String.class)
        .groupName("Customer Application")
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .select()
        .paths(myAppPaths())
        .build();
}
```

Hope this will help someone in future.